# Что такое "стереотип" в c#?

Tags: c#

К этому понятию относятся: классы, абстрактные классы, структуры...
Что такое "стереотип" в c#?

Comment: Где вы это услышали?

Comment: трехмерный тип данных

Comment: @Igor, стереотипы включают стереоклассы, стереоструктуры, стереоделегаты и прочие стереоперечисления

Comment: @Igor и ещё тогда фракталотип, это для фрактальной мерности тип.

Comment: Дмитрий, это шутка была.

Comment: В C# такого понятия нет, но оно есть в UML.

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего имелось ввиду обобщения `Generics`.

Пример использования:

```
List<string> items;
```

В данном случае `List<T>` это обобщение.

Обобщения предназначены для того что бы создавать классы, интерфейсы или методы параметризованные некоторыми типами для поддержки статической типизации, убрать дорогостоящее преобразование типов, какое было например раньше в `ArrayList`.

Более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_1.php) и [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.12.php).